# Final pressure of gases

Tags: thermodynamics

Theory question here:

If I have 4 sample of gases with same number of moles and same starting temperature, which one will have the highest pressure if I compress them 1/5 of its volume?

Will it be :
You have 4 samples of ideal gas, each of which contains the same number of moles of gas and has the same initial temperature, volume and pressure. You compress each sample to 1/2 of its initial volume. Which sample has the highest value of final pressure?
A monatomic gas compressed isothermally.
A monatomic gas compressed adiabatically.
A diatomic gas compressed isothermally.
A diatomic gas compressed adiabatically.

I'm thinking a diatomic gas compressed adiabatically, am I correct?

Comment: Tell us how you came to your conclusion

Comment: I know isothermal processes are out of the question, for mono vs diatomic, I was thinking since change in internal energy is higher in diatomic, it equates to work done, which in turn equates to PV. Since volume compressed is same, diatomic will have a higher pressure?

Comment: When you say work equates to PV, exactly what do you mean. Do you know the equation for reversible adiabatic work?

Comment: I figured out, it should be mono. The work done is   negative of the change in internal energy :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct that the adiabatic cases are the only ones to consider.  For an adiabatic reversible expansion or compression, we have $$PV^{\gamma}=const$$where $\gamma=1.67$ for a monatomic gas and $\gamma=1.4$ for a diatomic gas.  For an ideal gas, it then follows that $$TV^{(\gamma-1)}=const$$or $$\frac{T_2}{T_1}=\left(\frac{V_1}{V_2}\right)^{(\gamma-1)}$$This means that the temperature increase will be greater for a monoatomic gas than a diatomic gas.

Comment: seems like I'm thinking from another way. Could I ask how did you get $$TV^{(\gamma-1)}=const$$?

Comment: Just substitute P=nRT/V into my first equation.